# How can I get a custom message from WebApplicationException?

Tags: java, exception

I have a service A that makes post request to another controller (B). This is my service making post request. Controller B is not in the same project as service A, so B throws Bad request (400) and service A turns 400 request to `WebApplicationException`:

```
    WebClient client = tokenAuth.addAuthentication(WebClient.create(url))
                   .type(AccelaradMediaType.SMR_IMAGE_SHARE_V3_JSON)
                   .accept(AccelaradMediaType.SMR_SHARE_RESULT_JSON);
    String response = client.post(body, String.class);
    catch (WebApplicationException e) {
   //get message from exception and print
}
```

And this is other controller(B) that my service is making post request:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/shares")
    @Consumes({AccelaradMediaType.SMR_IMAGE_SHARE_V3_JSON, AccelaradMediaType.SMR_IMAGE_SHARE_V3_XML})
    @Produces({AccelaradMediaType.SMR_SHARE_RESULT_JSON, AccelaradMediaType.SMR_SHARE_RESULT_XML})
    public ShareResult shareV3() {

        ShareResult result = null;
        try {
            result = shareStudies();
        }
        catch (StudyShareException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public ShareResult shareStudies() {
        try {
            //some logic
        }
        catch (InvitationException e) {
            String message = "Invitation is pending";
            throw new StudyShareException(message, e);
        }
    }
```

And here are StudyShareException class and BadRequestException class:

```
public class StudyShareException extends Exception {
    public StudyShareException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

```
public class BadRequestException extends WebApplicationException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        this(message, null);
    }

    public BadRequestException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(cause, Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(message).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build());
    }
}
```

When service A makes a post request, it does go into the catch block and controller B prints out error in the stack trace with "Invitation is pending" message.

My goal is to print out "Invitation is pending" from service A as well. I tried e.getResponse() or e.getResponse().getEntity() or e.getMessage(), nothing has worked. Is it even possible to get custom message from service A? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you catching `WebApplicationException` in service A when service B is throwing `StudyShareException`? You need to catch the correct exception in service A

```java
try {
    WebClient client = tokenAuth.addAuthentication(WebClient.create(url))
                   .type(AccelaradMediaType.SMR_IMAGE_SHARE_V3_JSON)
                   .accept(AccelaradMediaType.SMR_SHARE_RESULT_JSON);
    String response = client.post(body, String.class);
    catch (StudyShareException e) {
   //get message from exception and print
}
```

Now if you are trying to catch all exceptions extending `WebApplicationException` then you should make `StudyShareException` extend `WebApplicationException` as well.

That being said, perhaps you shouldn't catch any exception at all just let service A just bubble up the exception thrown in service B. However, that's up to you, you may want to throw a different message or a different exception in service A.

Comment: B is another controller in another project. Therefore, it doesn't really throw exception back to service A, it returns 400 bad request, which causes `WebApplicationException` in service A.

Comment: Share more details about which `WebClient` are you using. include imports please. Also, what is the `body` you are passing and what is `tokenAuth`, include these details. Exceptions should bubble up in a `WebClient` call, at least if you are using spring's `WebClient` for example. Also, why `BadRequestException` passing null throwable? if you don't need the `cause` then just use the `WebApplicationException` constructor specified in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html#WebApplicationException-javax.ws.rs.core.Response- which just passes a `Response`.